# JavaScript. Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

Код:

```
const fetchSecondWordById = id =>
  new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ 11: 'World', 22: 'Task', 33: 'Duppy' }[id]), 10),
  );
```

Как вызвать, чтобы получить значение 'Duppy'?

Answer (score 1):

Функция принимает некоторый ID в объекте `{ 11: 'World', 22: 'Task', 33: 'Duppy' }` и возвращает значение по этому ID в resolve. Нужный Duppy это 33 `fetchSecondWordById(33)` и дальше получить результат через `then`.

```js
const fetchSecondWordById = id =>
      new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(() => resolve({ 11: 'World', 22: 'Task', 33: 'Duppy' }[id]), 10),
      );
    
fetchSecondWordById(33).then(
    result => console.log(result)
);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но как использовать это значение в основной программе?

Comment: @MyNick ну вы получили это значение в функцию, дальше в ней можете работать с ним любым способом `result => { /* тут любой код, который будет работать с результатом */ }`. Остальное зависит только от того, что ваша основная программа хочет и должна делать. Ну и да, это асинхронная операция, поэтому она может отработать уже когда весь остальной код прошел.